# Is it possible to install input methods via Terminal?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, command, input-method

Is it possible to install "**Traditional Chinese**" below via Terminal? What are the commands?

[image]

Comment: Use your package manager?

Comment: I want to use Terminal rather than Software Manager.

Comment: Which Linux/Unix-Distribution are you using?  Commands and package names to use on the cli will depend on that. And wich programs will you need traditional chinese for?  Because some of those will have their own language-packages, too.

Comment: I use Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. I want to key in Chinese characters on a text editor.

Comment: @ 炸鱼薯条德里克, what does "CLI" stand for?